# Changing app name after an In app purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to change the icon and the app name after an in app purchase is done in iOS?

The typical scenario would be a free app is available and through in app purchases the app gets a full version. In this case would it be possible to change the name and the logo of the app?

Answer (score 3):

No, both the app icon and name are stored in the Bundle which is readonly.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you may consider releasing two versions of your app:

- "My App Lite" - with a name and logo that matches the nature of this cutdown version.
- "My App" or "My App Pro" or similar, with a logo that strips the "lite" bar or text on the icon file, for example.

Comment: It is not possible, because apple rejects such apps, recently i tried to publish such kind of apps, lite and pro version and apple rejected the lite version. Publish "lite" version, make it available as "Pro" with inapp purchases.